# ASCII characters on iOS device compared to simulator

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios-simulator

I have a test application to see the ascii characters. Could any one explain to me why the ascii characters on different on the simulator compared to the iOS device and how to get the same ascii characters from the device?

Code:

```
for ( int i = 0; i < 256; i++ ) {
    NSLog(@"%d: %c", i, i);
}
```

sample of simulator results:
126: ~
128: Ä
129: Å
130: Ç
131: É

sample of iOS devcie results:
126: ~
128: √Ñ
129: √Ö
130: √á
131: √â

Thanks!

Comment: Those aren't ASCII (ISO-646) characters once you get to 128.

Comment: Ok. I thought they were called extended ASCII. So, I need to get the simulator 130 character when running the iOS device. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Oddly, Apple's documentation claims that `%c` format specifier should print non-ASCII characters as octal or unicode hex format, so you shouldn't be seeing those characters at all.

Comment: @Wooble that is why I'm confused. I don't understand why there is a difference between the simulator and the device ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because values greater than 127 aren't ASCII, otherwise known as ISO-646. These byte values get different glyphs depending on the encoding used to interpret them, which will vary between the real device and the emulator.

Comment: So, I need to get the simulator 130 character (Ç)when running the iOS device. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: @Sulthan I have tried \u00E7 which according to http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/e7/index.htm is the correct unicode character but I'm getting √ß in my logs.

Comment: @ErikRodriguez How do you check that? What font are you using? Is the font unicode, too?

Comment: @Sulthan I just NSLog() my string. I do not know what font the log uses.

Comment: @ErikRodriguez That's the problem. Try to display the characters using an unicode font (e.g. Helvetica), then ask questions :)

Comment: @sulthan that is essentially what I'm asking. How would I do that?

Comment: @ErikRodriguez Create a UILabel in your app and put the text there.

Comment: @Sulthan ok it does display correctly when I add it to a label, but I do not need to display it I need to send it as part of a string to a web service. Do I need to do anything special to make sure the encoding is correct?